# "Guillemet" arrows do not generate for buttons in Rails link_to helper

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

When I am putting a page together with Bootstrap, I have a primary button that looks ok with the "guillemet" arrows added to it, like so (denoted by &raquo):

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-md" href="#" role="button">Play Game 2 &raquo;</a>
```

I am trying to make a similar button in a Rails project when I generate a button using the link_to helper:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-md" <%= link_to "Play Game 1 &raquo", trivia_path %> </a>
```

When inserting the guillemet into the "Play Game 1" text, it delivers it as text and fails to generate an arrow. After experimenting with putting it in single quotes and moving it outside of the <%>, the page still renders it as text.

How do you generate styling like that within a link_to helper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work (no need to surround in the `<a>` tags as the link to helper will do that for you):

```
<%= link_to "Play Game 1 &raquo;".html_safe, trivia_path, class: "btn btn-primary btn-md" %>
```

Sorry, I misunderstood your original issue, but the edited code above should work - I tested it in a rails app and it looked fine.

Comment: Gave it a try. Still outputting the guillemet as text instead of arrows. One additional detail I forgot to mention was that the button above is in a row (thus within <td></td> tags). I thought this could be a potential reason why the arrows won't display, but even after moving the button out of the table, it still shows as text. Thanks though.